# How can I tell if an Actionscript object has a certain dynamic property on it?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, dynamic

I have a dynamic Actionscript class as follows:

```
public dynamic class Foo {....}
```

In my code I (may) add some properties to it:

```
myFoo["myNewDynamicProp"] = "bar";
```

Elsewhere in my code, given an instance of class Foo, how can I determine if that dynamic property has been added already without throwing an expensive exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do one of three things. First, calling a property that doesn't exist on a dyanmic instance doesn't throw an exception. It just returns `undefined`, so you can just test for that. Or you can use the `in` keyword. Or you can use the `hasOwnProperty()` method.

Consider the following:

```
var myFoo:Foo = new Foo();

myFoo.newProp = "bar";

trace(myFoo.newProp != undefined); // true
trace(myFoo.nothing != undefined); // false

trace("newProp" in myFoo); // true
trace("nothing" in myFoo); // false

trace(myFoo.hasOwnProperty("newProp")); // true
trace(myFoo.hasOwnProperty("nothing")); // false
```

You could also just as easily use bracket notation for the first example: `myFoo['nothing']`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [hasOwnProperty](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#hasOwnProperty%28%29)(property name) method for that :

```
if (myFoo.hasOwnProperty("myNewDynamicProp")) {
  // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also loop through the properties of any dynamic class using this:

```
for (var propertyName:String in myFoo)
{
  trace("Property " + propertyName + ": " + myFoo[propertyName]);
  if (propertyName == "myNewDynamicProp")
  {
      // found
      // may be do something
  }
}
```

This way you can not only check for your desired property, but also do more with the overall (dynamic) class properties.

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to do a simple null check like this:

```
if(myFoo.myNewDynamicProp) {
  //you can access it
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ah, good call, rushed a bit on that answer. Only would work for null check of a property defined on Foo class. Thanks. Wouldn't the chosen answer's first example not work either then?

Comment: Apparently Flex returns "undefined" when querying a non-existant dynamic property. But the real answer was the method "hasOwnProperty" which doesn't even show up in Eclipse as a method on my classes, but it works!